# F#: inefficient sequence processing

Tags: f#, sequence, primes, lazy-evaluation, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have the following code to perform the Sieve of Eratosthenes in F#:

```
let sieveOutPrime p numbers =
   numbers
   |> Seq.filter (fun n -> n % p <> 0)

let primesLessThan n =
    let removeFirstPrime = function
       | s when Seq.isEmpty s -> None
       | s -> Some(Seq.head s, sieveOutPrime (Seq.head s) (Seq.tail s))

    let remainingPrimes =
       seq {3..2..n}
       |> Seq.unfold removeFirstPrime

    seq { yield 2; yield! remainingPrimes }
```

This is excruciatingly slow when the input to `primesLessThan` is remotely large: `primes 1000000 |> Seq.skip 1000;;` takes nearly a minute for me, though `primes 1000000` itself is naturally very fast because it's just a Sequence.

I did some playing around, and I think that the culprit has to be that `Seq.tail` (in my `removeFirstPrime`) is doing something intensive. [According to the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.tail%5b't%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d), it's generating a completely new sequence, which I could imagine being slow.

If this were Python and the sequence object were a generator, it would be trivial to ensure that nothing expensive happens at this point: just `yield` from the sequence, and we've cheaply dropped its first element.

`LazyList` in F# [doesn't seem](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/reference/fsharpx-collections-lazylist-1.html) to have the `unfold` method (or, for that matter, the `filter` method); otherwise I think `LazyList` would be the thing I wanted.

How can I make this implementation fast by preventing unnecessary duplications/recomputations? Ideally `primesLessThan n |> Seq.skip 1000` would take the same amount of time regardless of how large `n` was.

Comment: [it is](https://ideone.com/MAzTKO). I tried your code with n=10000, 20000 or 100000, observed the same run time.

Comment: but changing the `m` in `primesLessThan n |> Seq.skip m |> Seq.take 10` indeed changes the time and reveals it runs at about *~m^3* [***empirically***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth), instead of the theoretical *~m^2* for your algorithm (producing *m* primes). cubic time is no picnic, for sure. :) (quadratic, too)

Comment: for *a* solution, see this [RosettaCode entry](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Functional) which [runs](https://ideone.com/VOIJ9i) at *m^1.4* empirically, at the tested range of  producing *m = 100K..200K* primes. It uses different algorithm as well as a different, custom-made, type. (disclaimer: I'm not the author).

Comment: @scrwtp has already linked to an answer that says this, but I'll repeat it here for anyone who finds this question: **don't use Seq.tail in recursive code**. You probably think that because List.tail is O(1), Seq.tail is also O(1). It's not. Seq.tail is O(N), and will cause an O(N) algorithm to become O(N^2), or an O(N^2) algorithm to become O(N^3) and so on. (I see that you've already figured that out, but I want to repeat it because this is the second most common mistake I've seen with seqs. First most common mistake is forgetting that they are lazy).

Comment: @rmunn In fact the reason I thought Seq.tail was O(1) was because the analogous concept in Python is O(1) - but the point is taken, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive solutions and sequences don't go well together (compare the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36459890/f-removing-duplicates-from-a-seq-is-slow), it's very much the same pattern you are using). You might want to inspect the generated code, but I'd just consider this a rule of thumb.

`LazyList` (as defined in FSharpX) does of course come with [unfold](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Collections/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Collections/LazyList.fs#L133) and filter defined, it would have been quite bizarre if it didn't. Typically in F# code this sort of functionality is provided in separate modules rather than as instance members on the type itself, a convention that does seem to confuse most of those documentation systems.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know `Seq` is a lazily evaluated collection. Sieve algorithm is about filtering out non-primes from a sequence so that you don't have to consider them again.

However, when you combine Sieve with a lazily evaluated collection you end up do the filtering of the same non-primes over and over again.

You see much better performance if you switch from `Seq` to `Array` or `List` because of the non-lazy aspect of those collections means that you only filter non-primes once.

One way to improve performance in your code is to introduce caching.

```
let removeFirstPrime s =
   let s = s |> Seq.cache 
   match s with
   | s when Seq.isEmpty s -> None
   | s -> Some(Seq.head s, sieveOutPrime (Seq.head s) (Seq.tail s))
```

I implemented a `LazyList` that works alot like `Seq` that allows me to count the number of evaluations:

For all primes up to 2000.

- Without caching: 14753706 evaluations
- With caching: 97260 evaluations

Of course if you really need performance you use a mutable array implementation.

PS. Performance metrics

```
Running 'seq' ...
  it took 271 ms with cc (16, 4, 0), the result is: 1013507
Running 'list' ...
  it took 14 ms with cc (16, 0, 0), the result is: 1013507
Running 'array' ...
  it took 14 ms with cc (10, 0, 0), the result is: 1013507
Running 'mutable' ...
  it took 0 ms with cc (0, 0, 0), the result is: 1013507
```

This is `Seq` with caching. `Seq` in F# has rather high overhead, there are interesting lazy alternatives to `Seq` like `Nessos`.

`List` and `Array` run roughly similar but because of the more compact memory layout the GC metrics are better for `Array` (10 cc0 collections for Array vs 16 cc0 collections for List). `Seq` has worse GC metrics in that it forced 4 cc1 collections.

The mutable implementation of sieve algorithm has better memory and performance metrics by a large margin.